# How do I implement a simple spinlock on std::atomic<T> so that the compiler doesn't optimize it out?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, optimization

I've been playing around with very simple ways to lock a thread using just standard C++11/14, and currently I ended up using something that looks like this

```
std::atomic<bool> setup_ready(false);

{
  // thread 1
  while (!setup_ready.load()) std::this_thread::yield();

  // do something
}

{
  // thread 2
  // perform some setup
  setup_ready.store(true);
}
```

Is there something that prevents the compiler from optimizing the `this_thread::yield()` call, and in turn the whole loop?

What if I removed the yield altogether and just wanted to do busy waiting like this? Is there a cross platform way to prevent the compiler from optimizing the loop away? Or does the standard prevent it when looping over an atomic?

```
{
  // thread 1
  while (!setup_ready.load()) ;

  // do something
}
```

The only solution I came up with was adding a volatile variable to the mix, but I'm not sure if that's the best way. I also tried checking the standard regarding atomics, but I coudln't find many details about specifics on compiler optimizations.

Comment: Most compiler optimizations aren't explicitly allowed by the standard; they're largely implementation dependent. I'm extremely doubtful any compiler would optimize out your loop, if you removed the yield. I know that gcc and cl certainly won't.

Comment: The compiler knows that atomics can change "spontaneously" thanks to writes in other threads, so it can't optimize the loop away.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "in turn the whole loop" - the loop contains 2 calls (`setup_ready.load()` and `yield`),  even if 1 of those calls is optimized out it doesn't imply that the other one would be.

Comment: BTW: (I did see a question on this once but can't find it now) implementing a spinlock with `yield` is considered bad.  The rationale is that `yield` can end up going away for quite a long time; but a spinlock should only be used in the first place on a situation where the code inside the lock is extremely fast (certainly not making any system calls).  IOW, if the spinning without `yield` would hurt performance then this is not a good place to have a spinlock in the first place, it'd be better to wait on a sync object.

Comment: @M.M Actually my first implementation didn't include the yield, but by adding it I was able to get a 10x performance increase. In the end I ended up switching to a condition variable anyway, but yeah, I see your point.

Comment: Optimizations aside, there's no *requirement* in the standard that the store ever becomes visible to the load. The standard merely says ["Implementations should make atomic stores visible to atomic loads within a reasonable amount of time"](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics#atomics.order-12), which is a normative encouragement (because of the "should") but not a requirement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is not allowed to optimize out `this_thread::yield()` unless it can determine that it's free of side-effects -- which it can't, because it's not.

The atomic load operation can't be optimized away, because it includes a memory barrier and is specifically defined to pick up modifications made by other threads.

Comment: Thanks for this, though from what I've read, `this_thread::yield()` is implementation defined, and since it's mostly a hint, it could be a NOP, which in turn would be free of side-effects and optimizable. At least that's what I got from reading the standard.

Comment: If it's a NOP, then it doesn't matter if it's optimized out.  It still has to run the loop to do the atomic load

Comment: Just because a function is a NOP doesn't mean the compiler can optimize it away. That's only possible if the function definition is visible to the compiler, which typically means it's inline, or you're doing interprecedural optimization (and it's unlikely that your C or C++ run-time provides the necessary info to enable IPO).

Comment: @JonathanWakely So if I have a call to a non-inline function that is completely empty, most compilers won't remove the call altogether? Or am I misinterpreting what you're saying?

Comment: That's what I'm saying. How can the compiler remove a call to a function if it doesn't know what the function does? (It doesn't necessarily have to be inline, but the function body has to be visible in the translation unit being compiled, which is only true for functions defined in the same translation unit, inline or not).